# About C# in ASP.NET and SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a drop down list that binding data from database table and I can show it, but when I wanna show the data when I selected the drop down list value, it can't show anything

Here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSource = GetData();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "DEPT_NAME";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "DEPT_NO";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=id;Password=pw"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TEL_NO,EMP_NAME,EMP_POSITION FROM tel WHERE DEPT_NO =" +value, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();                 

            this.GridView1.Visible = true;
            GridView1.DataSource = dr;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            dr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }               
    }
}

DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=id;Password=pw"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 'Please Select' AS DEPT_NAME , '000' AS DEPT_NO UNION SELECT DEPT_NAME , DEPT_NO FROM dept ORDER BY DEPT_NO ASC", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Check your DDL items query inside SQL Server, is it show any results? If yes, you may have wrong configuration either `DataTextField` or `DataValueField` when performing `DataBind`.

Comment: Thank you bro, I just try what you tell me to do and it show lots of data, but I don't know what is 『wrong configuration either DataTextField or DataValueField when performing DataBind. 』mean, would u mind to tell me more?

Comment: DEPT_NO  numeric or varchar ?

Comment: @Sami  DEPT_NO is varchar

Comment: That's the problem. change you SQL statement as in my answer.  in case of  WHERE DEPT_NO =" +value (where value is varchar), no record returned

Comment: Well, "wrong configuration" here means that you need to match `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` with proper field name or column alias returning from your query inside DataTable. Check DataTable contents with a breakpoint to show all columns inside it.

Comment: Thanks Bro , but in VS how to use breakpoint to show information for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TEL_NO,EMP_NAME,EMP_POSITION FROM tel WHERE DEPT_NO = @value", conn))

cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@value",value);
```

Query (   `"SELECT TEL_NO,EMP_NAME,EMP_POSITION FROM tel WHERE DEPT_NO =" +value`) will work if DEPT_NO dataType is number

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.NVarchar).Value = value;` is more proper way to declare SQL parameter.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, true or AddWithValue can be used.

Comment: Thanks Bro , now i change my code like this
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TEL_NO,EMP_NAME,EMP_POSITION FROM tel WHERE DEPT_NO = @value", conn))
                    {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = value;
                        conn.Open();
                        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {

                        this.GridView1.Visible = true;
                        GridView1.DataSource = dr;
                        GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: ok i solve the problem because i forget to set AutoPostBack="ture" haha Thank you guys =]